# How can I await my custom data flow block completion?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm working with ITargetBlock and have somewhat successfully created a custom data flow block. However, I can't wrap my head around implementing the "Completion" task. I currently define this as:

```
public Task Completion { get; }
```

Once I build my data flow line, I attempt to await this completion task but get a "null" object referenced. This is due to the fact that I'm not assigning the completion task to anything.

What should I assign this to? I would think it would automatically be associated with the data flow block but it defaults to nothing...

What should I assign Completion to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement your code `Completion` should complete once you have called `Complete()` and all "in flight" work finishes.

This can be done with a TaskCompletionSource

```
public Example<TInput>() : ITargetBlock 
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<Object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>()
    public Task Completion { get; }

    public Example()
    {
        Completion = tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        // We run this on a background thread because we don't want the call to Complete be blocking.
        Task.Run(() => {
            // Wait here for any currently executing async work your dataflow block does to finish.
            // ...

            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }
    }

    public void Fault (Exception exception)
    {
        // Cancel here any running work.
        // ...

        tcs.TrySetException(exception);
    }

    public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, TInput messageValue, ISourceBlock<in TInput> source, bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        if (Completion.IsCompleted)
        {
            return DataflowMessageStatus.DecliningPermanently;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This triggers the Completion task which is good! However, how does this work in conjunction with the "propagate completion" link option? Does triggering this completion source bypass the completion propagation?

Comment: No, what "Propagate completion" does is once the previous tasks state goes to "Completed" it will call Complete() on the next method in the chain as part of its self cleanup work.